# How to enable and disable selecting of <textarea> with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, selection, highlight

I was wondering how to disable and enable highlighting (text selecting) of a  element with JavaScript?

I would like something like the readonly property, where I can do

```
element.readOnly = true|false
```

only it would disable or enable the text highlighting in that field.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There may be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is possible to do this with CSS/JS. Here is something that may work for you:

**CSS:**

```
*.unselectable {
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;

   /*
     Introduced in IE 10.
     See http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/msUserSelect/
   */
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

For IE less than version 10 and Opera browsers, you will need to use the unselectable attribute of the element you wish to be unselectable. You can set this using an attribute in HTML:

...

This property isn't inherited, so you have to put an attribute in the start tag of every element inside the . You could instead use JavaScript to do this recursively for an element's descendants:

```
function makeUnselectable(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == 1) {
        node.setAttribute("unselectable", "on");
    }
    var child = node.firstChild;
    while (child) {
        makeUnselectable(child);
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
}

makeUnselectable(document.getElementById("foo"));
```

I also found additional methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting).

I did find out that this method will not work in chrome: "This doesn't have any effect on content loaded as chrome". But, there is a jquery solution that is known to have better compatibility which looks like:

```
$('textarea')
    .attr('unselectable', 'on')
    .css('-webkit-user-select', 'none')
    .css('-moz-user-select', 'none')
    .css("-ms-user-select","none")
    .css("-o-user-select","none")
    .css("user-select",'none')
    .on('selectstart', false)
    .on('mousedown', false);
```

If you still run into issues with being able to select text, you can do a onselect function, unselect.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to get this to work. Can you show me an example?

Comment: Do you fill the data in the text box with your own data is the user entering data?\

Answer (score -1):

Making it readonly does not prevent users from selecting the text.  To do that, you need to bind the selectstart event on the textarea and cancel it by doing a return false;.

Try this:

```
<textarea onselect="return false;"></textarea>
```

Note that there may be some browser inconsistencies - and also the fact that this can be incredibly annoying for users ...